# Javascript div breaks my google map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

Hi i am using the javascript code below to display google maps inside a show/hide div.

PS I want the map be hidden by default when the page loads. so i wrote this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

        // <![CDATA[
        function showlayer(layer) {
            var mymap = document.getElementById(layer).style.display;
            if (mymap == "block") {
                document.getElementById(layer).style.display = "none";
            } else {
                document.getElementById(layer).style.display = "block";
            }
        }
        // ]]>


    </script>

<div id="mymap" style="display:none;">
<? include $this->loadTemplate( 'map.php' ); ?>
</div>
```

the map.php file contains the code below:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6&amp;sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var mapLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $this->link->lat . ', ' . $this->link->lng; ?>);
            var mapOptions = {
              zoom: <?php echo ($this->link->zoom?$this->link->zoom:13); ?>,
              center: mapLatlng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
              scrollwheel: false
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: mapLatlng,
                map: map,
                title:"<?php echo addslashes($this->link->link_name); ?>"
             });
        }
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){initialize();});

    </script>
```

When i remove the style="display:none; everything works ok but i dont want to display the map on page load.

Any help ??

Comment: Java? Where is the Java?

Comment: How are you calling `showlayer`? Because your code relies on you specifying `layer` properly.

Comment: OOPSSS sorry for that. i mean Javascript

Comment: updated the post title.

Comment: @Takis, see my previous comment. How are you calling `showlayer`?

Comment: @Andy <p id="showorHide" class="showmap"><a onclick="javascript:showlayer('mymap')">Show Map</a>

Comment: Well that works fwiw http://jsfiddle.net/n2jUw/2/. Check your console to see if you have any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call initialize after you do `document.getElementById(layer).style.display = "block";` because there is a bug I think that does not center the maps correctly in the specified lat and long. So load the map, after the div is shown.

Comment: How can i load the map after the div is shown ?? Sorry for the question but i am newby in javascript. :(

Comment: Now you call initialize() when the dom is loaded, in the $.ready -> jQuery(document).ready(function(){initialize();});
Instead, call initialize() after document.getElementById(layer).style.display = "block";